# How to ensure same partitions for same keys while reading two dataframes in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Say I have two dataframes :

```
data1=[(0, 4, 2),
 (0, 3, 3),
 (0, 5, 2),
 (1, 3, 5),
 (1, 4, 5),
 (1, 5, 1),
 (2, 4, 2),
 (2, 3, 2),
 (2, 1, 5),
 (3, 5, 2),
 (3, 1, 5),
 (3, 4, 2)]
df1=spark.createDataFrame(data1,schema = 'a int,b int,c int')
data2 = [(0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 5), (1, 4, 5), (1, 5, 3), (2, 2, 2), (2, 1, 2)]
df2=spark.createDataFrame(data2,schema = 'a int,b int,c int')
```

so the dataframes on disk in a csv are like so:

```
df1.show()
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  0|  4|  2|
|  0|  3|  3|
|  0|  5|  2|
|  1|  3|  5|
|  1|  4|  5|
|  1|  5|  1|
|  2|  4|  2|
|  2|  3|  2|
|  2|  1|  5|
|  3|  5|  2|
|  3|  1|  5|
|  3|  4|  2|
+---+---+---+

df2.show()
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  0|  2|  1|
|  0|  2|  5|
|  1|  4|  5|
|  1|  5|  3|
|  2|  2|  2|
|  2|  1|  2|
+---+---+---+
```

I want to read them in and then merge them basis `a`. I can side-step the shuffle step if I can get same keys (`a`) on the same partitions. How do I:

1. Get the same keys on the same node? (I can do `df.repartition()` after `spark.read.csv` but, does that not first read the data into whatever partitioning spark sees fit and then repartitions it as I want? This shuffle is what I want to avoid in the first place
2. Once I succeed in step 1, tell spark that now the keys are on the same node and it does not have to go through the shuffle?

Comment: can you show a visual  of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you.

Comment: Use `.repartition("a")` after reading df1 and df2. Shuffle is never to be avoided at all, only reduced / contained. Sometimes shuffle is needed, like before a groupby / join on known keys. Try not to optimize things in Spark place, a lot of people worked hard so you don't have to :)

Comment: Thank you for your help Gaarv. However, as you can see in the setting of my question, that shuffle is completely unnecessary. Spark is still a generic solution that requires human intervention at different levels to extract maximum performance out of it. The question is if I can specify the partitioner at the time of reading. Would be very thankful if you can answer that

Comment: Not under this form sadly (CSV), the only alternative I can see would be to preprocess the data (doesnt have to be Spark) and to write back the data as Parquet which is a format that retains partition information, offers predicate pushdown and such. At reading, data will then be distributed but not shuffled.

Comment: Ohh .. that is strange. I thought spark didn't maintain partition information while saving. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351873/how-to-make-spark-use-partition-information-from-parquet-files .. where can I read more about formats that support saving in such a way that spark, later on, reads it as the partitions that it was saved with

Comment: It does if you saving data with `partitionBy` (also, I forgot - it works with CSV too - just doesnt have all the metadata that Parquet provides). Partitioning on disk allows for reading and querying optimizations.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#partition-discovery
https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/partitionby/

Comment: @Gaarv I am trying to test what you said but I am failing. I have asked a new question around the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70881933/understand-the-number-of-partitions-that-data-saved-with-partitionby-gets-read-i .. Can you please give it a look?